# AttributeError: module 'PySimpleGUI' has no attribute 'theme'

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, pysimplegui

I have try

```
sg.theme('DarkAmber')
```

but I got the error

> "AttributeError: module 'PySimpleGUI' has no attribute 'theme'"

```
software version:
python3.6, PySimpleGUI version:4.16.0
platform: ubuntu 16.04
```

Comment: Try `sg.ChangeLookAndFeel('DarkAmber')`

Comment: 4.16.0 has themes so it's likely an install error.  theme was just likely the first call tried.

Comment: it works. @MacItaly, thanks.

Comment: @drewhaha I created an answer for you to accept. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Try sg.ChangeLookAndFeel('DarkAmber')